# Jekyll does not compile scss

Tags: sass, jekyll

I want to upgrade a Site from Jekyll 3 to 4.0.0 but for some reason the SCSS is not compiled anymore (worked before).

I have a scss file in `assets/css/test.scss`:

```
---
---
$primary-color: green;

body {
  color: $primary-color;
}
```

The output in `_site/assets/css/test.css` looks like (a scss map?):

```
{
    "version": 3,
    "file": "test.css",
    "sources": [
        "test.scss"
    ],
    "sourcesContent": [
        "$primary-color: green;\n\nbody {\n  color: $primary-color;\n}\n"
    ],
    "names": [],
    "mappings": "AAEA,AAAA,IAAI,AAAC,CACH,KAAK,CAHS,KAAK,CAIpB"
}
```

My configfile contains this sass config:

```
sass:
  style: compressed
  sass_dir: _sass
```

The Gemfile.lock contains this installed sass-converter:

```
jekyll-sass-converter (2.1.0)
  sassc (> 2.0.1, < 3.0)
```

Ruby Version: ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

Gem Version: 3.1.2

Jekyll Version: jekyll 4.0.0

Any Ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The site uses the [jekyll-polyglot](http://polyglot.untra.io/) plugin. This plugin causes Jekyll to render scss source maps incorrect. See https://github.com/untra/polyglot#compatibility